# Python Composition Causes AttributeError

Tags: python, oop, nlp

I am constructing a Finite State Acceptor (FSA...basically, a tree). I have an `FSA` class and a `State` class, as an `FSA` should be made up of many `States`. When an `FSA` is initially created, though, I would like to create its beginning `State` and end `State`, and connect them. Here is the code for that:

```
class State (object):
    __slots__ = "chars","children"
    def __init__(self,chars,children=[]):
        self.chars = chars
        self.children = children

class FSA (object):
    __slots__ = "vocab"
    def __init__(self,vocab):
        self.vocab = vocab
        self.start = State("0")
        self.finish = State("1")
        self.start.children.append(self.finish)
        self.finish.children.append(self.start)
```

However, when I run `fsa = FSA("vocab.small")`, this throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'FSA' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Is there a way I can initiate the `FSA` and also create two `States` for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

```
__slots__ = "vocab"
```

What did you mean that to mean?  If you want to have a start attribute, you need to include it in your `__slots__` list, or don't use `__slots__` at all.  Unless you have a memory issue, you're better off just omitting the `__slots__` attribute.

Comment: Got it! This is part of a larger assignment, and slots are required. I didn't completely understand them, but now I'm getting there. Thank you.

Comment: "Slots are required" :(  When will the Java professors teach Python as it was meant to be written?